# Pattern Attribute: Require at least 1 non-whitespace character and allow white space before and after character

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to use the pattern attribute so that the form is able to submit as long as there's 1 non white space character in the form field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="agentName" name="agentName" placeholder="Agent Name" pattern=".*\S.*" title="This field is required">
```

However with this, the form doesn't submit if there's white space at the beginning or at the end. And it is adding in a period if I hit the spacebar after the character for whatever reason.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

This should take do the trick:

```
.*[^\S].*
```